# Is it save to put a command which includes a sudo command on the schedluer?

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, sudo

Good morning,

I am working on a link between my Laravel file server and a sinology backup.  The command I am using uses a sudo command to create and then disconnect the link.  I want to know if I would be able to run this command from the scheduler.

Thanks

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu version 16.04.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example (to run at midnight, every day):

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/your/command
```

This is a record you can add in `cron` of the user you use to run the command. Be aware `cron` have different environment so you should set all the variables you need.

You may need to create special shell script to include there your environment variables:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
/path/to/your/command
```

Comment: Hi  I am aware of how to put the command on the scheduler.  I need to know if it's safe to do so.

Comment: @Betty, why you think this is unsafe? And have you consider to run the command in cron of the user you want to switch to?

Comment: I need to run my command as sudo.  When I run the command on  a terminal, I am prompted for the password.  I'm afraid if I put it on  the scheduler, the system will be stuck waiting for a password; (Of course I don't want to provide it in the script, for obvious reasons) Though if I ran from the cron scheduler, it would automatically be run as root, but that wasen't the case.

Comment: You can run `cron` as any use you want, not need to be as `root`.

Comment: Here's my problem.  I already have one command which supposedly runs using sudo.  When I tried my new command on the scheduler, I was expecting the same result and didn't get it.